# How to route web server from localhost to LAN?

Tags: networking, routing

I develop web apps in microsoft visual studio on my desktop (ip = 192.168.8.2 , windows 10) . during development visual studio becomes essentially a web server bound to localhost:44396 . from there i can browse and test the web site by launching a browser to https://localhost:44396/ (please note that it is https with self signed cert that is created by visual studio).

what happens behind the scene is that when i click "start debugging" in visual studio , it goes in "server mode" and automatically configure iisexpress to become a server then launch a browser window for me that directly and automatically show the web site.

the problem is: i want to browse the web site from my ipad and android phones ( which are connected to to the same LAN and i am 100% positive that i can access a web server bound to 192.168.8.2 because i already did that).

how can i make my phone and tablet browse as if they were "inside" my desktop computer and access the development website ?

Comment: How that’ll work depends on what type of web app (ASP.NET Core?) you develop and how you launch it (directly or inside IIS Express). Please add these details to your question.

Comment: it is asp.net core app yes.i updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio, you can change this in the project properties:

[image: project properties]

In the lower section, enter the desired “App URL” instead of `http://localhost:whatever`, like `http://192.168.8.2:1234`. The URL at “Enable SSL” does not update until you save and re-open the project properties, unfortunately.

These settings are saved in `./Properties/launchSettings.json`, relative to the project directory.

---

If, on the other hand, you do not use IIS Express, the “App URL” will look slightly different. By default, it’s `https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000`. Changing it is straightforward. You can also *add* URLs instead of changing it, it’s a semicolon-separated list.

Comment: Thank you! i spent litrally 2 days looking for this but somehow all the stackoverflow and blogs that i visited didn't mention this. but in order for this to work VS need to be fired in admin rights , also the SSL certificate is not valid for 192.168.8.2.

Comment: Hm, unless you're trying to use privileged ports (<1024), it should work without admin. Answers to [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20036984/1025421) may be of interest regarding the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure that you can open the website from your development computer by going to https://192.168.8.2:44396

I'm not entirely sure you mean that you already have that part working, so that's why I added it, just to be safe.

Then, you should be able to do the same on your ipad. Instead of entering a domainname, enter https://192.168.8.2:44396

If that doesn't work, then ensure that port 44396 is open in your firewall. Given that this is not a native port, your windows firewall is likely blocking it from anything but your local pc (aka localhost) so you have to enable port 44396 to your entire network. You can safely set it to public because unless you make a portforwarding rule in your router, it won't be accessible from the internet.

Also make sure that port 443 is open, given that that's what https uses.

If you plan on opening this to the public, keep in mind that not all routers support NAT hairpinning, so you can't just enter your WAN IP into your browser and expect it to work. You will have to test that from outside the network to be sure.

Comment: no. the website is not accessible from my desktop by browsing to https://192.168.8.2:44396/ because visual studio bind only to localhost not to 192.168.8.2.

Comment: Then you have to alter the settings in Visual Studio first so that it will allow your internal IP Address first, or alter a setting in your object/code.

Comment: i tried hard enough. that is why i am asking here.

Comment: I think LPChip means is to reconfigure your project/task so that it *binds* to the local interface and not the loopback interface. Can you try looking on StackOverflow using these terms and the type of project you are working with in VS? For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725455/connecting-to-visual-studio-debugging-iis-express-server-over-the-lan) documents something similar.

Comment: @jvda yes, that's exactly what I meant. :)

Comment: i tried hard. visual studio wouldn't want to do it. SSL is the problem i think.